# why following Ant-Design Syntax not rendering anything?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, antd

I tried this way but no data is showing up and while compiling ,I'm not getting any error.I'm New to React , thanks in Advance

```
const Students = (props) => {
  let id = props.students;
  const [studentsData, setStudentsData] = useState(null);
  const url = "http://localhost:2021/students-data/" + id;
  console.log(url);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url).then((res) => {
      setStudentsData(res.data);
    });
  }, [url]);

  if (!studentsData) {
    return <Spin />;
  }

  //   console.log(studentsData)

  return (
    <List
      dataSource={studentsData}
      renderItem={(item) => {
        <List.Item key={item._id}>
          <Collapse style={{ minWidth: "257px" }}>
            <Panel header={item.name}>
              <Row gutter={[16, { xs: 8, sm: 16, md: 24, lg: 32 }]}>
                <Col className="gutter-row index" span={8}>
                  <div>Year Of Batch</div>
                </Col>
                <Col className="gutter-row value" span={16}>
                  <div>{item.yearOfBatch}</div>
                </Col>
              </Row>
              <Row gutter={[16, { xs: 8, sm: 16, md: 24, lg: 32 }]}>
                <Col className="gutter-row index" span={8}>
                  <div>Skills</div>
                </Col>
                <Col className="gutter-row value" span={16}>
                  <div>
                    {item.skills.map((e) => {
                      return e + " , ";
                    })}
                  </div>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </Panel>
          </Collapse>
        </List.Item>;
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default Students;
```

**why data is not rendering when I assigned collapse to renderItem attribute  ?**
what is the main issue here ? and how to modify current code to work properly

Comment: In your useEffect give props.students as dependency instead of URL and bring the URL making logic inside the useEffect.

Comment: I don't get it, URL is made up with props. students, so it does not matter right whichever we put as a dependency? anyways I tried your suggestion, still, no data Is showing up from this component

Comment: Whenever props changes the component will rerender. You are right your code might work. I wanted to make sure useEffect runs for every change of Id.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `return` keyword inside the `renderItem` props

It should be like this

```
//...
renderItem={(item) => {
        return (<List.Item key={item._id}>
          <Collapse style={{ minWidth: "257px" }}>
//...
```

In this case it works as expected

Comment: Yeah, Thanks a lot. It worked